# sed does not work properly when pattern comes from variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have question. Why sed does not work properly when pattern comes from bash variable? I prepared simple bash script to show it for you. There is some known reason why this happen?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=/tmp/egz.txt

# Creating example file
echo "First Line" > $file
echo "Second line" >> $file
echo "Third Line" >> $file
echo "Some other line" >> $file

sed_pattern="s|Some other line|Fourth Line|g"

sed -i "s|Some other line|Fourth Line|g" $file

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Sed with pattern works properly."
else
    echo "Sed with pattern works incorrect."
fi

sed -i $sed_pattern $file

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Sed with pattern from variable works properly."
else
    echo "Sed with pattern from variable works incorrect."
fi
```

On last Ubuntu result of this script is looks like this

```
Sed with pattern works properly.
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: undeterminated `s' command
Sed with pattern from variable works incorrect.
```

Comment: Put it in *double-quotes* `sed -i "$sed_pattern" $file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It works. Thx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because SED doesn't know he must interpret the variable.
Also, prefer simple quotes for your variable, to avoid the pipe being interpreted.

You can modify your code as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=/tmp/egz.txt

# Creating example file
echo "First Line" > $file
echo "Second line" >> $file
echo "Third Line" >> $file
echo "Some other line" >> $file

sed_pattern='s|Some other line|Fourth Line|g'

sed -i "s|Some other line|Fourth Line|g" $file

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Sed with pattern works properly."
else
    echo "Sed with pattern works incorrect."
fi

sed -i "$sed_pattern" $file

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Sed with pattern from variable works properly."
else
    echo "Sed with pattern from variable works incorrect."
fi
```

Comment: *...to avoid the pipe being interpreted...*, what do you mean by that?

Comment: just a programmer reflex... the habit of DRY run ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes near `$sed_pattern` variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=/tmp/egz.txt

# Creating example file
echo "First Line" > $file
echo "Second line" >> $file
echo "Third Line" >> $file
echo "Some other line" >> $file

sed_pattern="s|Some other line|Fourth Line|g"

sed -i "s|Some other line|Fourth Line|g" $file

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Sed with pattern works properly."
else
    echo "Sed with pattern works incorrect."
fi

sed -i "${sed_pattern}" $file

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Sed with pattern from variable works properly."
else
    echo "Sed with pattern from variable works incorrect."
fi
```

Output:

```
Sed with pattern works properly.
Sed with pattern from variable works properly.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that unquoted expansion of variable `sed_pattern` results in a shell command with arguments separated by the space character

In effect the second invocation of `sed` is like

```
sed -i s|Some other line|Fourth Line|g [... rest of cmdline...]
```

And in this cmdline the arguments are `sed`, `-i`, `s|Some`, `other`, `line|Fourth`, `Line|g`, and others.  The error message refers to the `s|Some` part where the `s` expression is incomplete after the 6th character (the exact error message depends on how the implementation of `sed` attempts to decipher the garbled command).

[Always use quotes.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)